# How do I debug MRTK UWP IL2CPP?

Tags: mrtk

Has something changed that broke the ability to debug UWP apps build from Unity with the latest MRTK?
When I build with Unity 2018.4.2f1, with developemnt and script debugging enabled and all 3 network related capabilities active, I can't attach VS to the running MR Portal app.
It does not even see it listed when using "Attach Unity Debugger".
Is there a proper documentation about debugging with the current state of software and SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

The following page has instructions on how to debug Unity UWP apps compiled using IL2CPP. This should work for MRTK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/managed-debugging-with-unity-il2cpp.

It's possible you're hitting an issue I think I saw mentioned in Unity's docs about attaching to a process running on the same machine. I'm trying to find the doc I'm thinking of, but I haven't found it yet...